# How to solve a differential equation of this kind.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation?

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-aky=k[b\frac{d}{dx}θ(x)(ay+c)]-\frac{1}{a}$$

Where θ(x) is a function given by $\sqrt{aR} (Tcosh\sqrt{aR} x-cosh(1-x) \sqrt{aR}$) 
And  a,b,k are contants.
The complementary function of the left hand side is

$y=A\cosh{\sqrt{ak} y}+B\sinh{\sqrt{ak} y }$
with boundary conditions $y(0)=\frac{1}{a}$ and $y(1)=\frac{s}{a}$
But it's difficult to get the particular solution because of the difficulty in separating functions of x and y.

Comment: This? $$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - aky = k\left(b\frac{d}{dx}\left[\theta(x)(ay+x)\right]-\frac{1}{a}\right)
$$

Comment: yes. Thank you.